# Drawing on a main class's subclass in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qframe

I have created a main class called widget.cpp, which inherits QFrame. And from widget.cpp I create a  subclass called frame.cpp in which I reimplement paintEvent() method for drawing image. The problem is that, when I try to draw image directly through widget.cpp by creating a paintEvent method for it , it works fine. But in the other case, when I implement it in the subclass frame.cpp its not working fine. Is there some thing I am doing wrong here.

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QFrame>
#include <QPainter>
#include "frame.h"

class frame;
namespace Ui {
    class Widget;
}
class Widget : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    frame * f;
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

[image]

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QFrame(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    f = new frame(ui->frame);
    f->show();
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

frame.h

```
#ifndef FRAME_H
#define FRAME_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>

class frame : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit frame(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *p);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // FRAME_H
```

frame.cpp

```
#include "frame.h"

frame::frame(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

}

void frame::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *p)
{
    QPainter* pPainter = new QPainter(this);
    QImage img(":/left.png");
    Q_ASSERT(!img.isNull());
    QRect source(0,0,20,10);
    QRect target(50,50,20,10);
    pPainter->drawImage(target, img,source);
    QWidget::paintEvent(p);
    QWidget::update();
}
```

If I use QRect target(0,0,20,10) in the above code the image is drawn.

testImage.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = testImage
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        widget.cpp \
    frame.cpp

HEADERS  += widget.h \
    frame.h

FORMS    += widget.ui

RESOURCES += \
    src.qrc

DISTFILES +=
```

widget.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Widget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Widget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>823</width>
    <height>468</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Widget</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>200</x>
     <y>60</y>
     <width>420</width>
     <height>300</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>420</width>
     <height>300</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumSize">
    <size>
     <width>420</width>
     <height>306</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShape">
    <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShadow">
    <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: From the first impression it looks like that you forgot to declare ``paintEvent`` as ``virtual`` and/or using the ``override`` keyword.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig It is not necessary to use override

Comment: @Som you can include the .ui file to be able to reproduce your code, which means: *not working fine.* ?

Comment: Its a bit confusing, because when I keep the  values of row in " QRect target(50,50,20,10);" from 0 - 80, the image is displayed properly. After that it gets shrinking and then disappears, the image resolution is only 20*10 and the widget is around 500*400. @PhilippLudwig virtual is not making any change.

Comment: @eyllanesc You are right, my bad.

Comment: @Som a query, you want `ui->frame` to be an object of the frame class you created?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes. I have attached the widget.ui file in question. Thanks for your help .

Comment: I think you're going the wrong way. To confirm my idea, ie you want the frame you used in the design to be the frame class you created, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes.  What I want is to insert the image within the frame in the design, and I have to do it via subclassing the widget.cpp. But I am not sure if I am doing it in the right way.

Comment: Thanks man , thats working.

Comment: Calling `QWidget::paintEvent(p);` in the end - is wrong. If you really need to draw original content - draw it at the begin of your `paintEvent` implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace a class X widget you must create a class that inherits from that class, in your case frame must inherit from `QFrame` and not directly from `QWidget`, since Qt Designer will use `QFrame` methods that `QWidget` does not have, instead a class that inherits from `QFrame` if it will have them.

So you should change the next part in your code.

**frame.h**

```
class frame : public QFrame
{
   ...
```

**frame.cpp**

```
frame::frame(QWidget *parent) : QFrame(parent)
{

}
```

Another error that is observed in your code is that you call `update()` inside `paintEvent()`, this can generate an infinite loop since `update()` calls `paintEvent()` indirectly. Also a widget your a painting space, this space we can get through the method `rect()`, if you draw outside that space not painted anything. Another bad practice is to create a pointer to `QPainter` since it will continually be called to that method and you will be creating memory in addition to that you are eliminating it correctly. From the above I propose the following code:

```
void frame::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *p)
{
    QWidget::paintEvent(p);
    QPainter pPainter(this);
    QImage img(":/left.png");
    Q_ASSERT(!img.isNull());
    QRect source(0,0,20,10);
    QRect target(50,50,20,10);
    pPainter.drawImage(target, img, source);
}
```

And most importantly, when you run `f = new frame(ui->frame);` you are creating a new widget that by default takes a position relative to the parent, that's why you see the image, but this is not appropriate, what you should do is promote the widget.

To promote right click on the `QFrame` that is in `QtDesigner`, and will be displayed a menu, select Promoted Widgets, opening a dialog window, in it you must put in Promoted class name the name of the class you have created, in your case **frame** , and in header file the .h file of your class, in your case **frame.h**, then press the add button and then the Promote button. As shown in the following images:

[image]

[image]

After compiling your project, as final recommendation change the name of the widget in Qt Designer of frame to another for example myFrame so that there is no confusion with the name of the class.

[image]

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/2d9e8ae64edade4d4090cba92819e000)